# How to delete nested element from mongo db based on conditon

Tags: python, mongodb

{
"_id":62749de1c511aff4354802f0
"filename":"anomaly-detection-using-amazon.pdf"
"tags":[
{'entity': 'Aws', 'count': 21},
{'entity': 'Keras', 'count': 1},
{'entity': 'Amazon Ml', 'count': 1},
{'entity': 'Amazon Cloudwatch', 'count': 1}
]
}

if value of entity string length less than 3 then output is

{
"_id":62749de1c511aff4354802f0
"filename":"anomaly-detection-using-amazon.pdf"
"tags":[
{'entity': 'Keras', 'count': 1},
{'entity': 'Amazon Ml', 'count': 1},
{'entity': 'Amazon Cloudwatch', 'count': 1}
]
}

This my document where i want to delete an entity key from tags array if length of the key value as string is less than 3

Comment: if number of characters in the value of entity field is less than three, then you want to remove that array element i.e object. Is this?

Comment: yes if number of character is less than 3 then looking for remove array element

Comment: What did you try? Please provide a valid sample document and expected result.

Comment: {
 "_id":62749de1c511aff4354802f0
 "filename":"anomaly-detection-using-amazon.pdf"
 "tags":[
  {'entity': 'Aws', 'count': 21}, 
  {'entity': 'Keras', 'count': 1}, 
  {'entity': 'Amazon Ml', 'count': 1}, 
  {'entity': 'Amazon Cloudwatch', 'count': 1}]
}

if value of entity string length less than 3 then output is

{
 "_id":62749de1c511aff4354802f0
 "filename":"anomaly-detection-using-amazon.pdf"
 "tags":[
  {'entity': 'Keras', 'count': 1}, 
  {'entity': 'Amazon Ml', 'count': 1}, 
  {'entity': 'Amazon Cloudwatch', 'count': 1}]
}

Comment: Please edit your question to put such information, instead of a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $set: {
         tags: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$tags",
               cond: { $gt: [{ $strLenCP: "$$this.entity" }, 3] }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Y5K7Bw7wD1B)

Comment: gives "errmsg" : "Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$set'",

Comment: [$set()](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/set/#mongodb-pipeline-pipe.-set): *New in version 4.2. The `$set` stage is an alias for `$addFields`*